# NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription removed, but still Bluetooth toggle in settings app is retained

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ios13, xcode11

We have recently removed anything and everything to do with Bluetooth from our app. This included even the `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` from info plist file. But for whatever reason when we upgrade our app from a version which had bluetooth to the one which doesn't anymore, the `Bluetooth` toggle in the settings app is still retained.

Is there a way to remove that as well. Its possibly because in the older version the user had been asked for permission and hence its being retained. But trying to see if there is any way to completely remove it as its misleading now

Comment: If you uninstall the older version and then do the fresh install of the new version, then i think bluetooth permission will not be displayed in settings.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, a fresh install is not having it as expected. But for existing users we can't ask them to do a fresh install. And since the code is completely removed, its a bit misleading that the setting is still hanging around

Comment: Oh Okay, but app permission behave like cache or UserDefaults. It keeps the last activity in memory unless you delete the application. I can only suggest to open settings from the app to allow the user to disable it by himself if it is active.

Comment: hmm.. understand that. Would be nice to have an option where we can remove it from code if we don't use it anymore in code.